# Embedded gate processing resources re-init does not take updated ontology

Tags: gate

We are using embedded gate in our service which is used for annotating documents. In this once we annotate a word it updates either a gazetteer or ontology. When we reload the document the newly added word should not be shown in the orphan list. For this we are re initializing processing resources while reloading the document. The issue we are facing is that if the word is added in gazetteer then it works properly and does not get shown in the orphan list but the word is added in the ontology then re initializing processing resource does not take the modified ontology instead it processes with the same ontology hence showing newly added word in orphan list. Can someone suggest how can embedded gate refer to modified ontology while executing the application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried option with Factory.deleteResources? From my experience this is only one options sometimes.